# JavaScript: Make 'enter' key on selected textbox do same function as form button

Tags: javascript

I have a form that has a textbox and a working submit button that runs a jquery/ajax function. I want the exact same function to run when the textbox is selected and the user hits 'enter' key.

I've tried making the textbox run the function, but either I make the text input no longer work, or it doesnt actually call the function (For example, it just puts a parameter in the url and refreshes the page...not what the function does). How can I make this work?

Here is my form code:

```
<form style="border: 1px solid;border-radius:5px;" >
    <div class="input-group mb-2 mr-sm-2 mb-sm-0">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="mytextbox" placeholder="ID #" name="parcel">
        <span class="input-group-btn">
            <button class="btn btn-success" id="btnSearch3" type="button" onclick="foo('parcel',document.getElementsByName('parcel')[0].value,'Wizard')">Search</button>
        </span>
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Use the `submit` event on the `<form>`, not the `click` event on the `<button>`. Also, use `type="submit"` on the `<button>`.

Comment: remember `e.preventDefault()` in your `keydown` if you end up using a `textarea` instead and don't want an actual carriage return.

Comment: @zzzzBov it's pretty obvious that this form doesn't actually submit data anywhere, so having a regular button instead of a submit button and handling click vs. submit isn't an issue.

Comment: @ScottMarcus, you'd be forgoing screen reader support and native support for form submission from various mobile keyboards if you chose to make that (poor) decision.

Comment: @zzzzBov Foregoing form submission support isn't an issue if you are not submitting anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To run javascript when a form submits, you can use `onsubmit`

If you also want to prevent the form from submitting in the regular way, you can use `event.PreventDefault`.

I made a fiddle, I've given the form an id and made an `onsubmit` function for it.
https://jsfiddle.net/qwza104q/.

If the button and form are going to run the same function, you should remove the button's `onclick` and add `type="submit"`.

Answer (score -1):

You need to set up the textbox to respond to keypress events so that you can check the input for the ENTER key press (`keyCode` 13).

Also, you shouldn't use inline HTML event handling attributes (`on...`) because they:

- Create spaghetti code that is hard to read and leads to code
  duplication.
- Create global anonymous wrapper functions around your attribute
  values that alter the `this` binding in the callback.
- Don't follow **[W3C Event Handling standards](https://www.w3.org/TR/2013/WD-DOM-Level-3-Events-20131105/#methods-1)**

Use `object.addEventListener("eventName", callback)` instead:

```js
// Get DOM references:
var btn = document.querySelector("#btnSearch3");
var txt = document.querySelector("#mytextbox");
var parcel = document.getElementsByName('parcel')[0];

// Set up event handlers:
btn.addEventListener("click", doFoo);

txt.addEventListener("keypress", function(evt){
  console.log(evt.keyCode);
  // Check for the ENTER key
  if(evt.keyCode === 13){
    doFoo();
  }
});

// General function to be called by both handlers:
function doFoo(){
  console.log("Callback called.");
  //foo('parcel', parcel.value, 'Wizard');
}
```

```html
<form style="border: 1px solid;border-radius:5px;" >
    <div class="input-group mb-2 mr-sm-2 mb-sm-0">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="mytextbox" placeholder="ID #" name="parcel">
        <span class="input-group-btn">
            <button class="btn btn-success" id="btnSearch3" type="button">Search</button>
        </span>
    </div>
</form>
```